# What could be the reason of exception at IDirect3DDevice9::Reset?

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-9, direct3d9

My employer asked me to fix annoying crashes in legacy Direct3D9 application.  Calls to IDirect3DDevice9::Reset method(while "Alt-Tabing") in fullscreen mode raise exception. DirectX 9 documentation says nothing about possible exception in IDirect3DDevice9::Reset.
Here is my D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS input parameter:

[image]

Codebase is HUGE and I have only minor OpenGL skills. Wasted some night already. Just have no idea where to search for error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you, comrade! Your tip about `FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz`is where error was hidden! My Mom always says attention deficit is key of 95% of my problems

Comment: :-) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks suspicious: `FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz`: "*For full-screen mode, the refresh rate is one of the refresh rates returned by `EnumAdapterModes`*".

Perhaps `0` means something else than `0 Hz` but if it doesn't, that could definitely be the cause of a division by zero